# installment for the openFoam, fail to add public key

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, gnupg, openpgp

When I install OpenFoam, I used the line provide online,

```sh
sudo sh -c " wget -o - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add-"
```

It gave an error and said

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

How can I resolve this and install OpenFoam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `curl`, which is easier in my opionin, or you can do it with `wget`, as I explain at the end.

### With `curl`

Replace your command with this, and it should work.

```sh
curl -sS http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

That command will get the key, and pipe it to `sudo apt-key add -`. `curl`, unlike `wget`, outputs to `stdout` by default, which is easier IMO.

### With `wget`

`wget` as you wrote it won't work. The command was mostly correct, but you made two errors when copying it, and that messed you up. This is the proper way to write it:

```sh
sudo sh -c "wget -O - http://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
```

That is pretty much the same as what you wrote, but with two major differences. The `-O` after `wget` is capital, which is what you want to change where `wget` outputs to. And second, I addded a space after `apt-key add`, but before the hyphen, which fixes a different error.

Comment: thanks guy ,much better

Comment: @YifengShen Glad to help! If I fixed your problem, can you please [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1081494)? You can do this by clicking the grey checkmark next to the vote buttons. Thanks!

Comment: sorry,mate this is the first time i use this website,i had do that ,lovely thank guy